# Liferay Navigation Hook

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

Is it possible to create a hook into Liferay Navigation?  I'd like to create one to interact with site changes.  For example, within site 'A' all portlets connect to DB schema 'A', but when in site 'B' the same portlets connect to schema 'B.'

I'm currently using a PhaseListener to get the site from ThemeDisplay and setting it in a global session variable - e.g.:

```
//get the theme display from the current request
ThemeDisplay theme = (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
theme.getSiteGroupName();  //connect to datastore based on this value
```

I feel it would be more effective to have this change based on site navigation to avoid putting this listener on all portlets.

Thoughts & comments?

Answer (score 0):

No. Connections are not made on demand, they come from a connection pool. So while you've been using A, connections have been opened in the pool pointing at schema A. When you would try to go to B, the connections in the pool are still good and open and available, so they would get pulled and you would still be using B.

Liferay doesn't really deal well with switching between schemas for any of the data it uses, and this kind of thing would probably wreak havoc on your environment.

Comment: I'm using MyBatis to handle datastore interactions.  In the RESTORE_VIEW phase of each portlet gets the current site and loads the appropriate environment; Mybatis should be handling connections/pools etc...  I'm only concerned with running this check (although very small) each time a portlet loads; hence a navigation hook, but I'm slowly starting to believe it's not possible.